# String Format Checking in Python

Tags: python

While preparing for my AS-Level Computer Science exam I came across a question in the pre-release material:

Prompt the user to input a User ID and check if the format of the ID corresponds with pre-defined formatting rules and output accordingly.

The Format (In order):

1. One upper case letter
2. Two Lower case letters
3. Three numeric characters (digits)

Example: "Abc123"

I came up with a solution using my language of choice(Python), however, I was wondering if there is a more elegant or better way to solve this. Especially the third check.

Here is my code:

```
#Task 2.2

u_id = input("Input User ID: ") #DECLARE u_id : string
numbers = [str(num) for num in range(10)]

#Checking if final 3 characters of User ID (u_id) are digits
for i in list(u_id[3::]):
    if i not in numbers:
        digit_check = False #DECLARE digit_check : bool
        break
    else:
        digit_check = True

#User ID format check
if (u_id[0:1].isupper() == True) and (u_id[1:3] == u_id[1:3].lower()) and (digit_check == True):
    print ("Correct Format")
else:
    print ("Wrong Format")
```

Ignore the DECLARATION comments. They are an exam requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Much easier/cleaner with regexp `/([A-Z])([a-z]{3})([0-9]{3})/` (something like that, it's been a while)

Comment: Given that you don't have a specific problem, this is perhaps not a great question for stackoverflow. There are probably better sites on the stack exchange network (maybe programmers?) for this question.

Comment: Learn about [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html). They are really useful for this kind of tasks.

Comment: `print('Correct Format' if re.match(r'[A-Z][a-z]{2}[0-9]{3}', u_id) else 'Wrong Format')` should do it.

Comment: @JCOC611 Thanks, I'll look into it. Haven't learnt regexp yet.

Comment: @Rook I guess that's true. I'll ask on programmers then...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are allowed to import [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

u_id = input("Input User ID: ") #DECLARE u_id : string

rex = re.compile("^[A-Z][a-z]{2}[0-9]{3}$")
if rex.match(u_id):
    print("Correct format")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

Explanation of expression:

- `^` represents the beginning of a string.
- `[A-Z]` is a range, containing all uppercase letters (in the English alphabet).
- `[a-z]` is a range, containing all lowercase letters.
- `[0-9]` is a range, containing all numbers.
- `{n}` specifies that **n** items (items are whatever is before the curly brackets) will be matched.
- `$` represents the end of the string.

Also, you can see more detailed explanations and test arbitrary strings against this *regular expression* [here](https://regex101.com/r/zD4gN9/1).

Comment: Only 2 lower case characters, plus you don't really need need to group them `()`. Good idea on the `$`, so you probably should have the start `^` too.

Comment: Lol I think it should be fine now. @AChampion thanks for the recommendations!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve it without regular expressions (mind you, in this case they are the right tool!), you could do something like this:

```
id_format = [
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", # or string.ascii_uppercase etc.
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    "0123456789",
    "0123456789",
    "0123456789",
]

def check(input):
    # check for same length
    if len(input) != len(id_format):
        return False

    for test, valid in zip(input, id_format): # itertools.zip_longest can make
        if test not in valid:                 # the length check unnecessary
            return False       

    return True

check("Abc123") # True
check("abc123") # False
```

Comment: `return all(test in valid for test, valid in zip(input, id_format)` would also work.

Comment: Good one for interview

Comment: You could also provide functions instead of strings (i.e `str.isupper, str.islower, str.isdigit...`) which could be more efficient.

Comment: @AChampion: That's beautiful!

Comment: @JCO611: I agree. I tried to create the clearest code possible, your regex solution is of course the "correct" one.